# Specific difference between _WIN64 and TARGET_X64 macros in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

Most of the time _WIN64 macro was working well with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 but TARGET_X64 not working well.Please explain these two macros with specific example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Visual C++ compiler predefines `_WIN64` when compiling for a 64-bit target.  To test for x64/amd64 specifically, test for `_M_X64` instead.  Consult [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170) for other macros that are predefined by the compiler.

`TARGET_X64` is defined by neither the Windows SDK nor the Visual C++ libraries or toolchain.  It must be defined somewhere else in your project or one of its dependencies.

Comment: But _WIN64 not automatically include in preprocessor.

Comment: It is.  This macro is predefined for all 64-bit builds.

Comment: I wanna know what is the really suitable/best macro for check whether an arbitrary x64 build(using VS 2008/2010); **_WIN64** or **Target_x64** ?

Comment: As noted in my answer and on the documentation page to which I linked,  test `_M_X64`.  It is defined for x64 builds; it is not defined for all other builds.

Comment: In the linked documentation: *"`_M_X64` Defined as the integer literal value 100 for compilations that target x64 processors or ARM64EC. Otherwise, undefined."* and *"`_WIN64` Defined as 1 when the compilation target is 64-bit ARM or x64. Otherwise, undefined."* So it isn't defined for *all* 64-bit targets. And I don't know what 64-bit ARMs would/wouldn't count as ARM64EC.

Comment: OK, I've googled it: *"Arm64EC is a new application binary interface (ABI) for apps running on Arm devices with Windows 11"*. Since that wouldn't have existed in 2014, I think the meaning of these macros has changed.

Comment: Looking at old versions of that page on archive.is and archive.org. [In 2008](https://archive.is/uYY4L) and [2012](https://archive.is/19As), we had: *"`_WIN64` Defined for applications for Win64. "* and *"`_M_X64` Defined for x64 processors. "*. By [2015](https://archive.is/OovLT) the wording had changed to *"`_M_X64` Defined for compilations that target x64 processors."* but the `_WIN64` description remained the same.